# Low-voltage LED Light string flickers when turned on, flickers go away after 2 mins

Tags: led, low-voltage

We have several low-voltage LED light strips in our light-up cabinets in the kitchen. They have all worked fine for 3 years. One of them has now started to flicker for a couple of minutes when turned on. After that it goes back to steady light. If I turn them on/of they all come back fine so it is only one out of more than 10 strings that behaves like this. They all have individual low-power converters so I assume I can switch two converters to see if the problem is within the light strip or converter. It is just odd that it started after 3 years, with no changes related to the power supplied in the house/kitchen area. Any idea why this has started? I assume the low-voltage power supply is most likely the problem...?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Your idea of swapping parts is probably the way to go, but other than that we can't really figure out what's wrong from here.

Answer (score 1):

### Most likely, it's the converter

Those are electronic power supplies, and they are made in China.   Fortunately they're also commodity items.  If you want a more quality version, try looking for a "meanwell" brand.

It might be the wiring, and that is a serious fire-starter problem at any voltage, but that's not likely if powering off/on fixes it.